# one to many display of records in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables **Booking** and **BookingPassengers**.

Can I create a View that will display all **Booking** Information for a single record  and all records in **BookingPassengers** that are linked by **BookingID**.

Each **Booking** record can have a number of **BookingPassengers** records

**Booking**
BookingID
BookingStart
BookingEnd
BookingPrice

**BookingPassengers**
BookingID
Name
Age
Sex

Regards
         MArtyn

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All booking information for one passenger :

```
  CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT Booking.*
                 FROM Booking
                 INNER JOIN BookingPassengers
                     ON Booking.BookingID = BookingPassengers.BookingID
                     and BookingPassengers.Name = 'John'
```

All information for each booking:

```
  CREATE VIEW v2 AS SELECT Booking.BookingID, BookingPassengers.Name
                 FROM Booking
                 INNER JOIN BookingPassengers
                     ON Booking.BookingID = BookingPassengers.BookingID
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a view showing each BOOKING and also ANY NUMBER of BOOKINGPASSENGERS that are linked to the BOOKING table

Comment: Great info - pointed me in the right direction, also made me get some indepth MySql traing - hope I can now help others out